# How to create dynamic array filter expression?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a function to filter array of objects based on given structure of object. So I have this object:

```
{
    "2": [
        {
            "fd_id": 16,
           ...others
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "fd_id": 2,
            ...others
        },
        {
            "fd_id": 3,
           ...others
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to filter another array based on this object. Like this;

```
const result = products.filter(item => {
                // returns array of numbers [1, 2, 3]
                const filters = item.filters;
                if(filters){
                    // Here must be refactored
                    return ((filters.includes(givenObj[2][0].fd_id))
                        && (filters.includes(givenObj[3][0].fd_id) || filters.includes(givenObj[3][1].fd_id)));
                }
            });
```

But this function must be dynamic. Because the input object may change. So for between each parent "&&", and between each children "||" condition must be applied. Thanks for any help. This is the link to example https://jsfiddle.net/cadkt86n/

Comment: Can you be more specific with the requirement and test data?

Comment: The requirement is, I need to be able to filter array of objects with dynamic data. While the object structure is same. Number of parent and child arrays may change.
So the return statement must be dynamic to be able to handle it.

Comment: You don't have an array of objects. You have an object that has arrays of objects as property values. You can't use `filter` on that object. None of your objects have a `filters` property either. Can you provide a [mcve] so we know what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you update the question with working value for `filters`, `givenObj`, so that the user dont need to guess anything from their side

Comment: Is the given object the thing that is changing, or is it the conditions which are changing? Or both?

It looks like you're trying to filter some product items, and those items have an attribute called `filters` which you can use to match against your given object. Right? In this way, you can see how many items match an input object. Am I right about that?

Comment: @QuinnDirks You are right! This is what I want to achieve. I have products array and inside it, there is filters array.  The object at the top may change, but the structure will remain the same. I would like to look for fd_id inside that filters.

Comment: How does product array look likes?

Comment: @Nitheesh  I have added jsbin link to the question.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Does that get the job done, or is it not quite right?

Comment: @QuinnDirks It is not quite right. Because filterObj may change. This is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function to loop the data will help.

**My Logic**

- Generate the list of `fd_id`s from the `groups` using `Array.map`
- Filter `products` array. Check for the matching combination in `filters` node of `products` array. Condition is there should be a matching combination in each nodes of `fdIdList` array.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var groups = {
  "2": [
    { "fd_id": 16, "fd_fRef": 2, "fd_ad": "35 - 50", "fd_siraNo": 255, "checked": true }
  ],
  "3": [
    { "fd_id": 2, "fd_fRef": 3, "fd_ad": "KURU", "fd_siraNo": 255, "checked": true },
    { "fd_id": 3, "fd_fRef": 3, "fd_ad": "KARMA", "fd_siraNo": 255, "checked": true }
  ]
}

// Aggregates the list of fd_id s - This wil be an array of arrays
// [[16],[2,3]] => This will be the value
const fdIdList = Object.values(groups).map(a => a.map(b => b.fd_id));

var products = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "filters": [2, 3, 4, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 31, 48, 309, 318],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "filters": [2, 3, 4, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 31, 48, 309, 318],
  }
];


// Check if there is a common element in each node of fdIdList
var result = products.filter(item => {
  const filters = item.filters;
  if (filters) {
    let isFound = true;
    fdIdList.forEach(idListNode => {
      isFound = isFound && idListNode.filter(value => filters.includes(value)).length > 0;
    })
    return isFound
  }
});

console.log(result)
```